# Why is the root variable in a Binary Tree a pointer the node and not the node itself?

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I am trying to implement a Binary Tree in C++ and was going through some tutorials online to learn more about it.

I noticed that all tutorials mention that the root variable of the Binary Tree should be a pointer to the root node and not the node itself. Example code:

```
struct Node {
  int data;
  Node *left, *right;
};

class BinaryTree {
  private:
     Node *root;
};
```

Why not make the root variable `Node root` instead and when I insert a node in the binary tree I can assign values to the root?

Comment: What if the tree is empty? It also simplifies some implementation details, specifically with loops and/or recursion.

Comment: It makes things easy, if you like to reshpae you binary tree. Especially, if the current tree shall be inserted into another tree. The root holds the same type as the childern.

Answer (score 0):

Since the root node is also a node, it can be deleted. If it is not a pointer, you would have to start copying nodes instead of just moving pointers.

It could also be `nullptr` if the tree is empty